# How to get multiple indexes of array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

`indexOf()` gives the only one index of the matched element but how we find all  indexes of matched element in JavaScript?

Comment: An element only has one index (ie. relative to its siblings), so I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you elaborate

Comment: @Betty, are you talking about a plain JavaScript array or what?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, he means `[1,2,3,1].indexOf(1)`

Comment: Explain your query with an example atleast

Comment: @ErikAllik that would make more sense, but why mention a 'matched element in jQuery'? I took that to mean elements in the DOM. Confusing question is confusing

Comment: btw, oops, I didn't see Betty's username before choosing the masculine pronoun — apologies!

Answer (score 1):

I  would do it as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.indicesOf = function(x){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i) => c === x ? p.concat(i) : p ,[]);
};

var arr = [1,2,3,4,1,8,7,6,5];
console.log(arr.indicesOf(1));
console.log(arr.indicesOf(5));
console.log(arr.indicesOf(42));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.indexesOf = function(el) {
    var ret = [];
    var ix = 0;
    while (true) {
        ix = this.indexOf(el, ix);
        if (ix === -1) break;
        ret.push(ix);
    }
    return ret;
};
```

and then

```
[1,2,3,1].indexesOf(1)
```

should return `[0,3]`.

Comment: I would just use `if (ix < 0)`

Comment: I would not, the doc explicitly says -1 is returned; http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp